# Why does my findViewById() not find my Id that I have introduced in my xml code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am very new to Android app development. But in one of my first projects I have come across an error. My `findViewById()` does not find an `Id` that has been introduced in the xml code.

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.fuzzylogic;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubtract);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Your total is 0"
    android:textSize="45dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="add one"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSubtract"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="substract one"
    android:textSize="25dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So either `add` or `sub` is null? Try cleaning your project, that shouldn't happen (assuming that really is `activity_main.xml`).

Comment: Try hitting File -> Save All

Comment: @323go has the right idea.  For any weird problems like this, always try first to refresh the project, and if that fails to clean it.  This solves an astonishing number of problems.

Comment: sub is somehow highlighted. I maybe a keyword or reserve name. Change the name of sub to say subButton.

Comment: @scriptocalypse and if that fails, install IntelliJ. Never be forced to clean a project for random bugs like this again. :)

Comment: @finn-stevenson Don't apologize your self if you ask here. We are used to that. You have put a well phrased question, but you should format your code better in the future. And if you got the right answer, tag and vote it up to say "Thank you". Welcome at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My findViewById() does not find an Id that has been introduced in the
>   xml code.

So this may cause:

- Errors in XML file(s) and then `R.java` is not correctly generated
- You did not save all edited xml files(ctrl+s)

So make it sure that you don't have errors in your project and clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

First you must save the xml file and the rebuild it

When u add a new file or changes to resource file , you better rebuild the project ,it will modify your R.java file corresponding to the changes you have made

and in `findViewById()` the id that we are passing is not the id from your layout xml file . actually it's an integer representation of the resource objects in R.java file

Note : If you are using eclipse chose automatically build option selected

Comment: before I got any answers, went into the R.java code and modified it myself to say:'public static final class id {
            public static final int action_settings=0x7f080000;
  public static int bSubtract;
  public static int bAdd;
  public static int tvDisplay;
    }'

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue, the reason why i was getting the issue was that R class was not updated with the new Xml file resources that i had added. So i rebuild the project and boom the issue was resolved.

So rebuilding the project might help.