# NullPointerException when creating OnClickListener (Android)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onclick, onclicklistener

This is a very simple android app. I'm just learning to write code for android now and I am unsure why the line: add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() throws a NullPointerException.

```
public class StartingPoint extends ActionBarActivity{

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container,  new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            counter--;  
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

}
```

Here is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.thenewboston.jaredh.StartingPoint$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/total"
    android:textSize="40sp" 
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/addButton"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/subButton"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:id="@+id/bSub"/>
```

```
Logcat Error:
       03-29 17:44:24.930: D/AndroidRuntime(25367): Shutting down VM
03-29 17:44:24.930: W/dalvikvm(25367): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41831898)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInf{com.thenewboston.jaredh/com.thenewboston.jaredh.StartingPoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at com.thenewboston.jaredh.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:39)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
03-29 17:44:24.940: E/AndroidRuntime(25367):    ... 11 more
```

As you can see it is a very simple app just adding 1 to the text field when either button is clicked. Any help could be greatly apprecitated. Just unsure why the NullPointerException is being caused.

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: is this code for `activity_starting_point`?

Comment: probability something is wrong with your bAdd and it cannot be instantiated, post some logcat error msg, I cannot see where it is falling

Comment: The first set of code is the java and the second the xml.

Comment: what is the name of xml file?

Comment: I've just seen someone post an almost identical question, this is from a guide online isn't it?

Comment: fragment_starting_point.xml

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737319/unfortunately-application-has-stopped-android-emulator-genymotion/22737675, this is same question

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826993/findviewbyidr-id-badd-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662546/findviewbyid-in-java-r-id-badd and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368694/why-does-my-findviewbyid-not-find-my-id-that-i-have-introduced-in-my-xml-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the XML you presented (without saying which file it really is, and despite that the XML text is not even valid) is the layout of the `PlaceholderFragment` you add at the beginning. However, the fragment is not immediately added, just scheduled to be added by the `FragmentManager`. Therefore when you are immediately trying to find its UI components, the activity fails to do so, and the `add` reference is set to null by `findViewById`.